# local storage not identifying array name

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to save an array of "items" in the cart. but when it goes on else section an error occur "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null" please help what's wrong with the code

```
var existing_cart = localStorage.getItem("cart");
existing_cart = JSON.parse(existing_cart);
console.log(existing_cart);

if (existing_cart.items instanceof Array) {

  existing_cart.items.push({
    'article_number': article_no,
    'quantity': quantity,
    'item_name ': item_name
  });
  console.log(existing_cart);
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(existing_cart));

} else {

  var products = [{
    'article_number': article_no,
    'quantity': quantity,
    'item_name ': item_name
  }];
  var cart = {
    'items': products
  }
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
  toastr.success('Have fun storming the castle!', 'Miracle Max Says');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in the else section? It looks like the problem is happening because existing_cart is null in your if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you run the code there won't be anything in the local storage, so `existing_cart` will be `null`. You need to check for this.

Change

```
if (existing_cart.items instanceof Array) {
```

to:

```
if (existing_cart) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var existing_cart = localStorage.getItem("cart") || '{"items":[]}';
```

In the case that it is the first time the code runs, the localStorage may not have the element, in which case it will return null or undefined.  In that case you can default it to a JSON that will allow the logic to flow without encountering null pointer exceptions.